# How to design Complications for watchOS 6 independent app?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I have an independent application on watchOS 6 and in my app I am using the Firestore REST API to show the data to the user using `URLSession`.

Since the Cloud Firestore REST API returns a JSON string, in order to process the data, I have created nested structs. Example: To access the 'title' in a particular response, I do something like this: `response.mapValue.fields.title.stringValue`.
The app works fine for now. In the long run I plan on creating the URLSessions as background tasks. Right now, I am calling `URLSession` every time the view is rendered by using `.onAppear(functionToUseURLSession())`) on my data's `List` view.

Now the next thing I want to implement is the complication for this particular app.
I am new to Swift and SwiftUI and am having the hardest time just getting started. All the tutorials I've been through online use `WKExtensionDelegate` to get the data models for the complication.
But in my case, I don't even have a data model! I just have structs calling other structs in a nested fashion in order to process the JSON response I get from the API call.

Any help allowing me to understand this is highly appreciated!

Here is some code to better understand the structure of the App:

```
struct Firebase: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var createTime, updateTime: String?
    var fields: FirebaseFields
}
```

Now, `FirebaseFields` is also another struct:

```
struct FirebaseFields: Codable {
    var emailID, lastName, firstName: String?
    var goalsRoutines: GoalsRoutines

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case emailID = "email_id"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case firstName = "first_name"
    }
}
```

Similarly, `GoalsRoutines` is also a struct...

As mentioned above, I have made these structs to follow the exact structure of the JSON object is get in response from Firebase API. So I access fields like: `Firebase.FirebaseFields.GoalsAndRoutines.whatever.is.my.firebase.schema`

My `GoalsView.swift` is:

```
var body: some View {
    List{
        ...
        ...
    }.onAppear{
        FirebaseServices.getFirebaseData() {
         (data) in self.data = data   
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, in `FirebaseServices.swift`, `func getFirebaseData` is:

```
func getFirebaseData(completion: @escaping ([Value]) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "FIRESTORE URL HERE") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        let data = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Firebase.self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(data.fields.goalsRoutines.arrayValue.values)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

So this is how I currently get the data and show it on the app.

I am really lost on how to do the same on my Complication.

Any help is really appreciated.